# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 - onDrawFrame - do I need to redraw all or is there any "world" with memory

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I developed some Android apps in Java, simple and moderately complex also with Canvas. Now I'm looking on OpenGL ES 2.0+. It's quite hard to start with something with to many new things and not quite satisfied tutorials (very often old for ES 1.x)

So my first question.

I thought that in opengl developer creates some sort of "world" (put objects with descriptors) and in some point change view (setLookAtM, orthoM) or move some of them by descriptiors). But all I found was that in each of onDrawFrame I have to create whole scene new.

Am I looking wrong or it is right?

For now I have some grid 20x20 of 2D textured (actualy using 144 different texturees) rectangles with scroll support. On nexus 5X OK, on older S3 mini very slow. Redrawing every each of them every each frame is not logical for me.

Comment: You don't have to create the whole scene. All your textures, vertex buffers, etc, only need to be created once. You have to **draw** the whole scene for every frame, though.

Comment: I know about textures, vertex buffers, these I initialize in onSurfaceCreated , but still. In every each frame build whole scene new with thousands of polygons is ilogical for me.